# FreeRadius SQL authorization and perl authentication

Tags: freeradius

Is it possible to achieve with FreeRadius something like this?

Check if a user is in SQL table:

- if yes: authenticate with Perl module
- if no: deny access

I studied the wiki and the FreeRadius SQL how to. As far as I understand, if you add users to radcheck, you need to have the password there, too. The SQL module handles the whole authentication process using a SQL database and this is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The SQL module is the easiest implementation... with perl to authenticate you'll still need the query result... see [Run SQL statements](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=124426)

Comment: I want to store only the usernames in SQL. User tries to authenticate on a portal, sends info to radius, check SQL if user exists, if it is there, pass the authentication to a perl module that will do it's magic with an external server. Basically, an authorization.

Comment: You'll still need a query result from somewhere to send to freeradius.  You're doing the authentication backwards.  Read [RADIUS Concepts](http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/Concepts).  If the entire cycle passes freeradius then authenticate the user on the portal, using the portals database not free radius.  If the user exists in free radius but not on the portal, you inadvertently created a backdoor.

Comment: I would prefer using unlang than perl for doing such thing in FreeRadius. However, actually FR has a well defined method and tables for MySQL, and you do not need perl at all. You should however, check their user group and their manual. It is easier than inventing stuff.

Comment: Thank you two for your interest in my question! I have a Cisco VPN where I do 2 factor authentication (VPN>Radius+Perl module>2FA solution). In order to restrict the roles of specific users I need to pass a certain radius attribute to the Cisco VPN for a pool of 100 users, something like memberOf. I wanted to do the authorization with sql and then pass the authentication to perl module so I will authenticate and generate the one time password there. If you are thinking at any other way of doing this, I am opened to suggestions.Maybe I can only manualy set a radius attribute in the reply?